# Alt tag is blank for WordPress images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, alt

I have the issue where I cannot figure what's missing exactly to declare the image alt tag. The website page is posted in here -

https://www.njoyn.com/blog/

I am also posting the code for the template. It will be really great if you can help figure this out. Please check the code here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
get_header();
?>
<?php
$page_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
?>

<div id="bd">
    <div class="blog-sec">
    <div class="container blog-main">
       <h2>Blog</h2>
        <div class="blog_left">

           <?php

$args     = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()):
        $my_query->the_post();


        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
?>

            <div class="blog_blocks">
                <div class="blog_thumb"><a href="<?php
        echo get_permalink();
?>" ><img src="<?php
        echo $feat_image;
?>" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="blog_content">
                    <h5><a href="<?php
        echo get_permalink();
?>" ><?php
        the_title();
?></a></h5>
                    <?php

        $content = substr(get_the_content(), 0, 115) . "...";
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo $content;

?>
                   <a href="<?php
        echo get_permalink();
?>" class="readmore"> 
                        <?php
        if (get_bloginfo('language') === "en-US") {

            echo get_option('of_blogtext_eng');
        } else {

            echo get_option('of_blogtext_french');
        }
?>
                                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
    endwhile;
}
?>

        </div>
        <div class="blog_right">

            <?php
if (is_active_sidebar('blog')):
?>

            <?php
    dynamic_sidebar('blog');
?>

            <?php
endif;
?>
       </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Please let me know what elements I need to add them to the array, or declaring Image variable and write an echo statement between for the ALT tag.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking us how you should code that `alt=""`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole chunk of code there that's not really necessary:

`$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));`

```
<img src="<?php
        echo $feat_image;
?>" alt="">
```

Remove the `$feat_image` line and replace the 2nd bit with

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

Using the `the_post_thumbnail()` function will output the necessary HTML and automatically fill in the alt text, provided of course that the text has been entered on the image post in the media library.

Hope that helps